# How do I get the char for a keypress knowing only the ConsoleKey enum and Modifiers?

Tags: c#, powershell, console, keypress

I want to create a [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance of the matching closing brace of any open brace typed in a PowerShell session (I'm using [PSReadline](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine#readme) to do the key handling). For your convenience, here are the properties of all the keys involved

```
PS> while($true){ [System.Console]::ReadKey($true) }

    KeyChar     Key    Modifiers
    -------     ---    ---------
          [    Oem4            0
          ]    Oem6            0  
          {    Oem4        Shift
          }    Oem6        Shift
```

In the key handler, I am given the `ConsoleKeyInfo` for the "chord" that was pressed (and PSReadline does filtering, so I already know I'm receiving only an `Oem4` or `Shift+Oem4`). I want to generate the matching `ConsoleKeyInfo` so I can send the pair printing to the console.

The [`ConsoleKeyInfo` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes

- a `char`
- a `System.ConsoleKey`
- a `bool` each for Shift, Alt, and Control

I can get the correct `ConsoleKey` by casting it to an `int` and moving up two...

```
PS> [System.ConsoleKey]([int]$key.Key + 2)
Oem6
```

And I can map from the pressed key's `Modifiers` by testing it bitwise...

```
PS> ($key.Modifiers -band [System.ConsoleModifiers]::Shift) -ne 0
False
```

But, I have no idea how to get the literal `char` for this console key. How does the console get the char from the keyboard key? Can this only be done with a live console/keyboard?

I'd rather not maintain a map of the key pairs nor split the handlers, one for each "chord", and hardcode the matching key char. :(

Comment: Look at my example for "InsertPairedBraces" here https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/blob/master/PSReadLine/SamplePSReadlineProfile.ps1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need to create a ConsoleKeyInfo just for PSReadline.

Occasionally you may need to pass a ConsoleKeyInfo to a method in PSConsoleReadLine, but most methods in PSConsoleReadLine that accept a ConsoleKeyInfo don't even look at the argument.  That's why the parameter is Nullable.

This doesn't actually answer your question though.  JaredPar is absolutely correct that in general, it's not possible to convert a ConsoleKey/ConsoleModifiers pair to a char.  If we don't care about full generality (and currently PSReadline doesn't), you can use code similar to what PSReadline uses:

```
internal static char GetCharFromConsoleKey(ConsoleKey key, ConsoleModifiers modifiers)
{
    // default for unprintables and unhandled
    char keyChar = '\u0000';

    // emulate GetKeyboardState bitmap - set high order bit for relevant modifier virtual keys
    var state = new byte[256];
    state[NativeMethods.VK_SHIFT] = (byte)(((modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) ? 0x80 : 0);
    state[NativeMethods.VK_CONTROL] = (byte)(((modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) ? 0x80 : 0);
    state[NativeMethods.VK_ALT] = (byte)(((modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) ? 0x80 : 0);

    // a ConsoleKey enum's value is a virtual key code
    uint virtualKey = (uint)key;

    // get corresponding scan code
    uint scanCode = NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(virtualKey, NativeMethods.MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

    // get corresponding character  - maybe be 0, 1 or 2 in length (diacriticals)
    var chars = new char[2];
    int charCount = NativeMethods.ToUnicode(
        virtualKey, scanCode, state, chars, chars.Length, NativeMethods.MENU_IS_INACTIVE);

    // TODO: support diacriticals (charCount == 2)
    if (charCount == 1)
    {
        keyChar = chars[0];
    }

    return keyChar;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't really do this.  Keyboard input is not as simple as a keyboard key + modifier = a character.  Instead it's more that a sequence of keyboard key + modifier values = a character.  In English keyboards this sequence tends to be of length 1 but in other languages the sequence can be much longer.  This means that generally speaking this isn't a solvable problem because one key can't definitely produce a given character

Michael Kaplan has a fabulous blog series that goes through this in great detail

> http://www.siao2.com/2006/04/13/575500.aspx

Comment: PSReadline ignores this issue w/o any complaints so far - it's not possible to provide a custom binding for keys that can't be represented by a ConsoleKeyInfo.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to insert the closing brace then you should be able to do what this handler does - it does the same for single and double quotes:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord "Ctrl+'","Ctrl+Shift+'" `
                         -BriefDescription SmartInsertQuote `
                         -Description "Insert paired quotes if not already on a quote" `
                         -ScriptBlock {
    param($key, $arg)

    $line = $null
    $cursor = $null
    [PSConsoleUtilities.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)

    $keyChar = $key.KeyChar
    if ($key.Key -eq 'Oem7') {
        if ($key.Modifiers -eq 'Control') {
            $keyChar = "`'"
        }
        elseif ($key.Modifiers -eq 'Shift','Control') {
            $keyChar = '"'
        }
    }

    if ($line[$cursor] -eq $keyChar) {
        # Just move the cursor
        [PSConsoleUtilities.PSConsoleReadLine]::SetCursorPosition($cursor + 1)
    }
    else {
        # Insert matching quotes, move cursor to be in between the quotes
        [PSConsoleUtilities.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("$keyChar" * 2)
        [PSConsoleUtilities.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref]$line, [ref]$cursor)
        [PSConsoleUtilities.PSConsoleReadLine]::SetCursorPosition($cursor - 1)
    }
}
```

It may not work on all keyboards AFAIK but I'm guessing you're only interested in getting this to work on your keyboard.  :-)